# Polygon.io WebSocket Connection Feedback Slow

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Currently I'm using polygo.io websocket connection on my cloud webpage. But the respond for the data fetch is really slow. Is there any way I can improve the data fetch speed?

Comment: upgrade internet speed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.